# Relations in points fibre are relations in base category

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathcal E $ be a category with finite limits and let consider the points fibre $\text {Pt}_Y $ over an object $ Y $ and the projection $\pi:\text {Pt}_Y \to \mathcal E$.

The question is: relations are preserved under $\pi $?
The answer seems to be negative, since the image under the projection of a jointly monic pair of morphism is not necessarily jointly monic.

On the other hand, in Borceoux Bourn work on Mal'cev categories, the proof of theorem 2.2.9, on characterization of Mal'cev categories in terms of points fibre, use a similar implication on relations.

Comment: What is "the points fibre"? Do you just mean $\mathcal{E}/Y$?

Comment: I mean the category whose objects are pairs (p , s) of split morphisms that's $ p\circ s=1 $ and morphisms $ f:(p, s)\to (p', s') $ satisfying $ f\circ s=s'$ and $ p'\circ f=p $.